# Design Choices for storing images on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm developing an application that I'm thinking of hosting on GAE, hopefully within the free tier. It's an "own-time" project and I find the GAE documentation pretty incomprehensible when it comes to working out which products are available, how much they cost, and how they should be used.

The app relies on users being able to upload images with some meta data. The meta data needs to be searchable and allow the images to be displayed.

My problem comes with where to save the images. I'm storing the metadata in the DataStore. Google seem to imply that I should store the images in either Cloud Storage or the Blob Store, with a preference for Cloud Storage. This seems to be chargeable.

I also see mention of the Image Service - is this something else I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

From [Default Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket):

> Applications can use a Default Google Cloud Storage bucket, which has
>   free quota and doesn't require billing to be enabled for the app. You
>   create this free default bucket in the Google Cloud Platform Console
>   [App Engine settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings) page for your project.

So you can use GCS without being charged as long as you don't exceed the free quota.

You also probably want to stick with the standard environment for its free quota. From [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing):

> App Engine applications run as instances within the [standard
>   environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment) or the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).
>
> Instances within the standard environment have access to a daily limit
>   of resource usage that is provided at no charge defined by a set of
>   [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas). Beyond that level, applications will incur charges as
>   outlined below. To control your application costs, you can set a
>   [spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit). To estimate costs for the standard environment,
>   use the pricing calculator.
>
> For instances within the flexible environment, services and APIs are
>   priced as described below.

And for images-related options, from  [Overview of Images API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/):

> [Java 8 on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8) supports Java's native image manipulation
>   classes such as [AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) and [Java2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-intro.html) alongside the App Engine
>   Images API.